# Send Email Directly From JavaScript using EmailJS

Tags: javascript, html-email, email

Send Email Directly From JavaScript using EmailJS.

Please look the below answer and I'm getting so many comments for malicious attacks.. because this file is loading in browser so malicious user can easily get your key configuration. So, how to avoid it?

```js
 var templateParams = {
    to_name: 'xyz',
    from_name: 'abc',
    message_html: 'Please Find out the attached file'
  };

  emailjs.send('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', templateParams)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('FAILED...', error);
    });
```

Comment: What problem are you seeing when executing this code?

Comment: How to avoid malicious attacks?

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can directly send email through using EmailJS without using the server side code. It'll totally client side.

For sending you need to configure below details.

1)First,Go to this site [https://www.emailjs.com/] and create free account.

2)below 'Connect your email service' button click and configure. You'll get 'YOUR_SERVICE_ID'

3)Then 'Create email template' button click and configure. You'll get 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID'

4)click on 'Send email from JavaScript' button. You'll get code.

5)You'll get the 'YOUR_USER_ID' in [https://dashboard.emailjs.com/account]

I did all configuration and added code please check. below code.

NOTE : -  "Please encrypted or embedded your use_id for malicious attacks."

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2.4.0/dist/email.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    emailjs.init("YOUR_USER_ID"); //please encrypted user id for malicious attacks
  })();
//set the parameter as per you template parameter[https://dashboard.emailjs.com/templates]
  var templateParams = {
    to_name: 'xyz',
    from_name: 'abc',
    message_html: 'Please Find out the attached file'
  };

  emailjs.send('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', templateParams)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('FAILED...', error);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you give everyone that visits your site access to your service key when you use it like that? Thus the person may misuse your service key for e.g. sending spam mails.

Comment: Okay Thank you..!! I didn't given service key anywhere..Could you please help me where is it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with email.js but I'm just wondering what prevents a malicious user from reading the JavaScript code of your website that is loaded into his browser and start making unwanted requests using your USER_ID and the templates.

Comment: This seems like a Really Bad Idea for the reasons mentioned by @Endzeit. It's also a really great example of why you _shouldn't_ try and embed a whole lot of email functionality in the front-end.

Comment: Hello @verandaguy there is no embed data or our URLs it's just example.. I didn't attach any personal URL so malicious user can send me spam mail.. it's a simple example for developer who can easily configure emails looking this...

Comment: Could you please tell me where should I do embed? And give me example once... it'll be helpful to me..

Comment: You say you need the `emailjs` API keys/bearer tokens/whatever to make calls to emailJS's service to send out emails. These tokens have to exist in your JS code base, which is served to the client. The client could extract these tokens and abuse the `emailjs` service while masquerading as you. You should not embed this kind of data in a client-side app, period.

Comment: I got you thank you for giving information.. I'll do it embed... could you give suggest me how should I do embed in JavaScript..?

Comment: Embedding this data client-side is a bad idea, and you shouldn't. To be clear, this isn't the kind of lesson that you want to learn by making this kind of mistake.

Comment: Okay.. Thank you.. because malicious can be re-embedd easily.

Comment: @Prabhat no, because you should never trust a client with your own genuine credentials for a service, including API keys. Your clients are totally free to extract, misuse, and abuse these, including to impersonate you and victimize other users.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript can expose your credentials like user id , service id to the public. For this , you can store these keys values in a variable (half value) and then manipulating it in runtime like appending remaining half of the key etc. But its not totally safe.

**Code :**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact Us</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card col-md-6 offset-md-3" style="margin-top:50px;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <label for="thename">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thename" placeholder="Enter Name">
        <label for="themail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="themail" placeholder="Enter Email">
        <label for="themsg">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="themsg" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="margin-top:10px;" onCLick="sendemail();">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function sendemail() {
      var userid = "YourUserID"
      emailjs.init(userid);
      var thename = document.getElementById('thename').value;
      var themail = document.getElementById('themail').value;
      var themsg = document.getElementById('themsg').value;
      var validmail = /^w+([.-]?w+)*@w+([.-]?w+)*(.w{2,3})+$/;
      if (thename == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Name");
      }
      else if (themail == "" || themail.match(!validmail)) {
        alert("Please Enter Valid Email");
      }

      else if (themsg == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Message");
      }
      else {
        var contactdetail = {
          from_name: thename,
          from_email: themail,
          message: themsg
        };

        emailjs.send('YourServiceID', 'YourTemplateID', contactdetail).then(function (res) {
          alert("Email Sent Successfully");
        },
          reason => {
            alert("Error Occur");
          })
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure to replace "YourUserID" , "YourServiceID" & "YourTemplateID" with your own ids

Reference : [Narendra Dwivedi - Send Email From JavaScript](https://www.narendradwivedi.org/2022/01/send-email-from-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2.4.0/dist/email.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    emailjs.init("service_ud48moz"); //please encrypted user id for malicious attacks
  })();
//set the parameter as per you template parameter[https://dashboard.emailjs.com/templates]
  var templateParams = {
    to_name: 'xyz',
    from_name: 'abc',
    message_html: 'Please Find out the attached file'
  };

  emailjs.send('service_ud48moz', 'template_njhhxon', templateParams)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('FAILED...', error);
    });
</script>
```